# Elasticsearch : AssertionError while getting index name from alias

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

We have been using **Elasticsearch Plugin** in our project. While getting **index name** from **alias** getting below error

**Error**

```
   {
   "error": "AssertionError[Expected current thread[Thread[elasticsearch[Seth][http_server_worker][T#2]{New I/O worker #20},5,main]] to not be a transport thread. Reason: [Blocking operation]]",  "status": 500
   }
```

**Code**

```
    String realIndex = client.admin().cluster().prepareState()
                   .execute().actionGet().getState().getMetaData()
                   .aliases().get(aliasName).iterator()
                   .next().key;
```

what causes this issue?? Googled it didn't get any help

Answer (score 1):

From the look of the error, it seems like this operation is not allowed on the transport thread as it will block the thread until you get the result back. You need to execute this on a execute thread.

```
public String getIndexName() {
    final IndexNameHolder result = new IndexNameHolder(); // holds the index Name. Needed a final instance here, hence created a holder.
    getTransportClient().admin().cluster().prepareState().execute(new ActionListener<ClusterStateResponse>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(ClusterStateResponse response) {
            result.indexName = response.getState().getMetaData().aliases().get("alias").iterator().next().key;

        }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable e) {
            //Handle failures
        }
    });
    return result.value;
}
```

There is another method for `execute()`, one which takes a listener. You need to implement your own listener. In my answer, I have an anonymous implementation of Listener.

I hope it helps

Comment: I tried this, able to get index name from alias value but after that still getting the same error

Comment: I didn get this. Error after getting the index name? Where and is it the exact same error.?

Comment: After removing **_JAVA_OPTIONS= -ea** from Environment Variables everything works fine. Even i could run without the above code. Sometimes ago while running  unit test with **ElasticsearchIntegrationTest** I was forced to add **_JAVA_OPTIONS** in the Environment Variables. Need to debug why does it require in Elasticsearch Unit Test and why does it cause error in plugin?